# How report errors in dbpedia ontology

Tags: ontology, dbpedia

I've started to come across interesting errors in dbpedia.

The linguistic concept of part of speech is of type television station https://dbpedia.org/page/Part_of_speech

Actual parts of speech categories like adverbs and adjectives are of type Food https://dbpedia.org/page/Adjective

I've been looking for a good way to report the errors, but my google fu fails me. I know that this repository is where the dev dbpedia is https://github.com/dbpedia/dev.dbpedia.org

Answer (score 0):

Best path is probably to report issues on the relevant repository on GitHub -- likely the [DBpedia Ontology Issue tracker](https://github.com/dbpedia/ontology-tracker), where "we keep track of modification requests in the DBpedia Ontology", or possibly the [DBpedia Information Extraction Framework](https://github.com/dbpedia/extraction-framework), the "software used to extract structured data from Wikipedia". You may prefer to start a conversation on the [DBpedia Forum](https://forum.dbpedia.org/), or to do some digging on the [DBpedia Wiki](https://www.dbpedia.org/).